# Error - 400 Quota exceeded: Your table exceeded quota for imports or query appends per table

Tags: google-bigquery

i constantly getting this error when i'm using Python script to execute queries.
however when i copies and execute the queries directly in Bigquery web console i'm not getting this error.
any thought what might it be or what to check/change?

Comment: Are you exceeding any of listed BigQuery quotas? https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/quotas

Comment: You mentioned a script.  People might be able to provide better answers if you added the script to the question.  Without the script, people have to guess at the possible causes when helping.  Also, without more details, the question runs the risk of being closed.